# how to calculate working hours from api data in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, datetime, calculation

i have fetched data from an api which contains employees working time,
i want to calculate total working hours each day

here's how i get the data from the api for 1 single day

```
 Future<List> getPunchData(String empCode,  DateTime date) async {
String ip = await confObj.readIp();
DateTime end = new DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day, 23,59,59);

final response = await http.get(Uri.parse("url/$empCode&$date&$end" ));
final String t = response.body;
var jsonData =jsonDecode(t);
return jsonData;
}
```

the api result is this:

```
 {
 "id": 10,
 "punch_time": "2022-03-08 13:30:19.000000",
 },
 {
 "id": 11,
 "punch_time": "2022-03-08 16:22:39.000000",
 }..
  ..
  ..
```

how can i automatically calculate and isplay total hours when after the widget is loaded

Comment: What is "punch_time"? Is that total working hours? If it is, you can convert the string into dateformat.

Comment: @ChiragBargoojar I think the first punch time refers to the time they start working and the second one is the time they finish working. The desired output could be found by just parsing both times to datetime type and then finding the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parse` function of the DateTime object to convert the `String` date into `DateTime`.

The code would somewhat look like this (can't say for sure as I don't know your API):

```
final DateTime startTime = DateTime.parse(jsonData[0]['punch_time']);
final DateTime endTime = DateTime.parse(jsonData[1]['punch_time']);
```

Once you have the DateTime object, you can use the difference function to get a Duration object which will tell you the hours an employee has worked.

```
final Duration durationWorked = startTime.difference(endTime);
final int hoursWorked = durationWorked.inHours;
```

Comment: how to make the calculation method automatically work when i load the widget/page (after i get the api data )

Comment: You could do this calculation in the `FutureBuilder` you might be using before returning a widget.